# Connect This GUI with autohotkey scripts?

Tags: html, css, autohotkey

I'm making this test project. Just found out how to make HTML a GUI for autohotkey

Just trying to figure out how to make my <a href="#" items in the list when you click, it activates a autohotkey string or does a script. trying to figure it out

```
type he
```

```
(
<body>
  <h1 class="logo">
    AUTO
  </h1>
  <h5 class="promo-text">
    Thank you for using Auto :) follow us on discord! {link}
    </h5>


    <div id="options">
        <table style="float: left">
          <tr>
            <hr style="width: 399px;">
            
            <td>[1] <a href="1_NUKE.html">Sign In Account</a>
                 <br>
                 [2] <a href="#"> Unfriend all friends</a>
              <br>
            [3] <a href="#"> Delete and leave all servers </a>
              <br>
          [4] <a href="#">New servers</a>
              <br>
          [5]  <a href="#">Scan for items</a>
              <br>
          [6] <a href="#">Typer</a>
              <br>
          [7] <a href="#"> Auto-image</a>
              <br>
          [8]  <a href="#">Google Search</a>
              <br>
          [9] <a href="#">Set-Date </a>
                   </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <table style="float: left">
          <tr>
          <br>
            <td>[10]  <a href="#">Filler</a>
              <br>
                [11] <a href="#">Profile Changer</a>
              <br>
          [12] <a href="#">[Beta testing for features] </a>
              <br>
          [13] <a href="#"> Filler</a>
              <br>
          [14] <a href="#">  Videos</a>
              <br>
          [15] <a href="#">Contact Report</a>
              <br>
          [16] <a href="#">Chat Scannerr</a> 
              <br>
          [17] <a href="#"> Information</a>
              <br>
          [18]<a href="#">Settings</a>
        
      
      
      </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        
      </div>
      




  </body>

  



  <style>
    body { 
        background-color: #f3f6f4;
        text-decoration: none; 
        align-items: center;
        margin: 0 auto; 
        
  display:flex; flex-direction:column; justify-content:center;
  min-height:100vh;
}

    



     #options td {  
        color:RED;
        

     }

     a { 
      text-decoration: none; 
      color: gray; 
      font-family:initial;
     }

     .promo-text { 
      color:aliceblue;
      font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
      font-weight: lighter; 
     }
     
     .logo { 
        font-family: Arial; 
        font-size: 100px; 
        color: red; 
     }

     a:hover { 
      color: red; 
     }
  </style>

  </html>
)
```

```
Gui, -DPIScale
Gui, Margin, 1, 1
Gui, Add, ActiveX, vText w1101 h632, htmlfile
Text.write(html)
Gui, Show
Return

GuiClose:
   ExitApp
```

I want the links to work with autohotkey like if I were to send a input or something

Comment: It's hard to say, if you do not mind on format, you could just create separate `Text` controls and bind callbacks to Click events. You might also consider checking out WebView2's [port](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=95666) to AutoHotkey. Try to post messages through JS and parsing them through WebView2.

Comment: Why not just use ```Gui, Add, Link,, [1] <a href="C:\pathToFile\File.ahk">Sign in account</a>```

Answer (score 0):

Put all 3 files in same directory and run `GUI.ahk`.

Save this as `GUI.ahk`

```
#SingleInstance Force

Run, Copy HTML GUI Link Href.ahk

html := 
(LTrim
"
<body>
  <h1 class=""logo"">
    AUTO
  </h1>
  <h5 class=""promo-text"">
    Thank you for using Auto :) follow us on discord! {link}
  </h5>


  <div id=""options"">
    <table style=""float: left"">
      <tr>
        <hr style=""width: 399px;"">

        <td>[1] <a href=""D:\Programming\AutoHotKey\GUI Open Exe File From Anchor Tag In GUI\Sign In Account.ahk"">Sign In Account</a>
          <br>
          [2] <a href=""#""> Unfriend all friends</a>
          <br>
          [3] <a href=""#""> Delete and leave all servers </a>
          <br>
          [4] <a href=""#"">New servers</a>
          <br>
          [5]  <a href=""#"">Scan for items</a>
          <br>
          [6] <a href=""#"">Typer</a>
          <br>
          [7] <a href=""#""> Auto-image</a>
          <br>
          [8]  <a href=""#"">Google Search</a>
          <br>
          [9] <a href=""#"">Set-Date </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table style=""float: left"">
      <tr>
        <br>
        <td>[10]  <a href=""#"">Filler</a>
          <br>
          [11] <a href=""#"">Profile Changer</a>
          <br>
          [12] <a href=""#"">[Beta testing for features] </a>
          <br>
          [13] <a href=""#""> Filler</a>
          <br>
          [14] <a href=""#"">  Videos</a>
          <br>
          [15] <a href=""#"">Contact Report</a>
          <br>
          [16] <a href=""#"">Chat Scannerr</a> 
          <br>
          [17] <a href=""#""> Information</a>
          <br>
          [18]<a href=""#"">Settings</a>     
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</body>

<style>
  body { 
    background-color: #f3f6f4;
    text-decoration: none; 
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto; 

    display:flex; flex-direction:column; justify-content:center;
    min-height:100vh;
  }
  #options td {  
    color:RED;
  }

  a { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: gray; 
    font-family:initial;
  }

  .promo-text { 
    color:aliceblue;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter; 
  }

  .logo { 
    font-family: Arial; 
    font-size: 100px; 
    color: red; 
  }

  a:hover { 
    color: red; 
  }
</style>

</html>"
)

Gui, -DPIScale
Gui, Margin, 1, 1
Gui, Add, ActiveX, vText w1101 h632, htmlfile
Text.write(html)
Gui, Show
Return

GuiClose:
GuiEscape:
ExitApp
```

This line executes AutoHotkey script, just change the path to script:

```
<td>[1] <a href=""D:\Programming\AutoHotKey\GUI Open Exe File From Anchor Tag In GUI\Sign In Account.ahk"">Sign In Account</a>
```

This is the `Copy HTML GUI Link Href.ahk` which runs on the 1st line of `GUI.ahk`.

1. `~LButton::` Sends Left Mouse Button Click, the ~ operator doesn't sends the Left Mouse Button Click, otherwise it wouldn't send the Left Mouse Button Click, but what we put in the script after Left Mouse Button
2. `MouseGetPos, , , , control` checks if we are located in the GUI.ahk window. If we are then the control is `AtlAxWin1`.
3. Empty the CLIPBOARD, send Right Click Mouse Button, Copy Shortcut
4. If CLIPBOARD is not empty, it copies the link `href` value, then 2 `StringReplace` are executed, 1st if the href contains `path/file` then `about:` is replaced with "" and only the `file/path` remains, then 2nd `StringReplace` if href is `#`, `blank#` is replaced and we get empty string.
5. `Run, %CLIPBOARD%` runs the `file/path` or if CLIPBOARD is empty then doesn't run anything.

```
#SingleInstance Force
~LButton::
CopyHTMLGUILinkHref:
MouseGetPos, , , , control
If control contains AtlAxWin1
{
    CLIPBOARD := ""
    Send, {RButton}
    Sleep, 50
    Send, {t}
    Sleep, 50
    If (CLIPBOARD != "")
    {
        StringReplace, CLIPBOARD, CLIPBOARD, about:, , A
        StringReplace, CLIPBOARD, CLIPBOARD, blank#, , A
        If (CLIPBOARD != "")
        {
            Run, %CLIPBOARD%
        }
    }
}
Return
```

This is the `Sign In Account.ahk` script:

```
#SingleInstance Force
SignInAccount:
MsgBox, 262144, , Sign In Account
ExitApp
Return
```